# What should I do with this audit? Is it a bug?

Tags: bug, reviewing, design, review-audits

While reviewing new posts I found a very bad quality post. There was nothing to edit (it was nonsense) so I tried to flag it as "very low quality" but it told me I have already raised that flag. So I thought my job was done (flag raised) and I clicked on <kbd>No Action needed</kbd>.

[image]

Then the system told me it was an audit and I have failed it...

[image]

I eventually clicked on <kbd>I understand</kbd> but this is a lie.. *I don't understand* what I was supposed to do. The system even advised me to flag as "very low quality", which I had already done.

Is it a bug? What should I have done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should have been an "I'm Done" option that's normally greyed out until you take an action. Here's the same dialog box from Stack Overflow:

[image: First question help]

I suspect the "I'm Done" button is invisible in your screenshot because of the recently added design. So I'll check with Stéphane on that.

It turns out you flagged the answer as "Not an answer" right after it was posted. So that's why you couldn't flag it again. Probably there should be a check to avoid auditing people with posts they've already flagged. So I'll check with a dev for that bit.

So it's two bugs working together to demonstrate [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law).

Comment: Re: the invisible button - it's definitely a CSS bug. Buttons that are marked as disabled have #fff foreground and background rendering them effectively invisible (you can also see it on the main site if you create a question and add an image - the "Add picture" button on the modal is white until you select a file).