# Puzzling updated site theme is ready for testing!

Tags: discussion, design

As part of implementing the new unified themes across the network, we're gradually rolling out updated site themes for each site. As of today, we have enabled your updated site theme for testing.

If you can't see it right now, that's by design! This is a very early test implementation of your design and we need your help finding issues with it before we make it live for everyone permanently. So, keep in mind, there will be things that need fixing! We'll address those things as we can.

If you'd like to review it, here's how:

### How do I enable it?

[Click here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) and check the "Beta test new themes" option. This will turn on the new theme for all sites that have one in testing, including this one. *Here's [more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314542/opt-in-to-beta-testing-new-themes) on how to opt in.* You can uncheck the box to revert to the older theme until the site is live for everyone. **Note, while turning it on is immediate, it will take a few minutes to revert to the old view - *but it will go through!***

### What type of feedback do we need?

#### On this post: Bugs related to this site's design elements

Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

This could include colors of sections of the design or text, problems with JavaScript add-ons (if applicable), the logo or top banner appearance or other artwork.

You can also feel free to ask questions about the new layout if you're unsure how to navigate it.

#### On Meta Stack Exchange: General concerns about left nav or theming

There are some things that are definitely changing everywhere and can't really be adjusted on a per-site basis. A few of them include:

- Top banner is shorter in height, so some artwork has to be adjusted along with some logos.
- Left Navigation is active everywhere (but can be collapsed into a menu by visiting your site preferences - [instructions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311237/284336)).
- Responsive layout is active, which lets the site adjust as browser widths change - no side scrolling (some pages haven't been updated, yet, though). For now, if you prefer the scrolling, you can disable this by clicking the "disable responsiveness" link in the footer.
- Many site elements including tags and voting arrows are standardized across the network.
- Link underlining is active. In an effort to make links more visible, they are now being underlined.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

As I mentioned earlier, there are some unique design elements like voting arrows and tags that are being standardized in this process. Keeping these custom elements makes our ability to maintain the sites too complex and, while we're very sad to see them go, we're in a difficult position of needing to make the site designs work together so that we can continue to address feature requests and bugs that will make your Q&A experience better. This is addressed in a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) if you want more detail.

### What new themes?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background). To follow along with the rollout of these new themes, go [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post).

### Thanks so much for your constructive feedback!

#### Oh, Who am I?

If you don't know me, I'm one of the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do?s=1%7C141.4591) here at Stack Exchange. I'm here to listen to your input and convey it to our Design team for responses and fixes to bugs. I'll do my best to respond to your concerns and explain whether changes we've made are bugs that can be changed or if they're by design and why.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Similarly to EKons' answer, these buttons look like bad actions (like Ignore a tag or Block the newspaper perhaps) - could we make these more friendly?

> [image: Red buttons]

Comment: That is quite striking and not in a good way. I'll see if we can get a less, um, intense color.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks for the change

Comment: These have been updated to be blue. :)

Answer (score 7):

Very minor one, but on a slightly sluggish connection, the title logo flashes red before the image appears because the alt text ("Puzzling") is not the same colour as the logo text.

[image: slow connection title flash]

The offending CSS (logo text is `#2d4254`):

```
.site-header .site-header--link {
    color: #ff554f;
}
```

The font size is also different, but that's less of an issue.

Comment: Well, that's puzzling.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> [image: My ask profile box]
>
> Better now, I think. (Jon)

[image: Deleted user?]

Is this a deleted account? <sup>Psst, it's not.</sup> [This](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4306/75921) is essentially the same thing, over Academia.SE. This red tint is confusing and distracting, the contrast is too high. Just like how this issue was solved there, I suggest making the background of the question asker blue instead.

Comment: Our designer is going to do the same magic here he did there.

Comment: @JonEricson May it be voodoo or anything else, as long as I can concentrate on the puzzles better, it's OK. :-P

Comment: Oh, I'm in an answer. Cool.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [review](/questions/tagged/review) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the First Posts and Late Answer review queues, the disabled button is invisible

[image]

instead of merely grayed out, like on a dozen other sites I checked:

[image]

**Update:** seems to be fixed now; also, the buttons are now green instead of red:

[image]

Comment: Well, that's disconcerting. I haven't been able to reproduce just yet because there aren't any items in those queues at the moment. But I'll add it to the list.

Comment: This is actually a [regression of an old bug](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/what-should-i-do-with-this-audit-is-it-a-bug/4951#4951) (assuming it ever got fixed, I can't actually remember...)

Answer (score 2):

(If this should be merged with the previous answer, please comment)

Review queue leaves big gap once queue is cleared which looks like something has been lost:

> [image: New site review queue cleared gap]

What it looked like with the old theme:

> [image: Old site review queue cleared]

EDIT: This appears to be to do with the responsive bottom bar.

Gif of vertical size change (only first second or so of clip is relevant):

> [image: Gif showing what happens when window is resized]

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you share your browser and OS details?

Comment: @JonEricson Windows 10.0, Chrome 70.0. I just checked and it still comes up (also on Puzzling Meta and Codegolf, though the latter is less visible due to the lack of background).

Comment: Hmmm... I can't reproduce with that setup. Is it possible you have a user script that might affect this? Also, have you tried changing the size of your window? (I can't find dimensions that cause the problem, but maybe I'm unlucky.)

Comment: @JonEricson I've got AdBlock, Adobe Acrobat, Google Docs Offline, Google Translate, Docs, Postman, Sheets and Slides listed in my extensions. It seems to be a problem of the responsive bottom bar: the empty space goes up and down depending on the height of the browser. I'll attach a clip soon (as well as a new problem :p).

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed when I scroll through a page quickly the link to the homepage in the upper left seems moves up and down as if vibrating. As far as I know this wasn't happening before and is likely not supposed to be happening.

If I am mistaken about this let me know and I'll remove this response.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce. Would you mind sharing your browser and OS details?

Comment: @JonEricson Ericson Browser is Microsoft edge and OS is Windows 10

Comment: I still can't reproduce. Is it possible you have some extensions installed? It might help to get an animated screen capture. (I've had good luck with [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/).)

Comment: Huh. The background gradients shouldn't look like that either. It should be smooth transitions, not hard lines. I'll note this for the designer in case he's seen something like this in the past.

Comment: @JonEricson - the background gradient issue is almost certainly just the gif compressing the colour space, not an issue with the site itself.

Comment: @Alconja: Good point. We'll see if we can reproduce the real issue.

Comment: @JonEricson - Just noticed that I am not seeing either issue now. Not sure how long it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When the window is resized, sometimes the background doesn't load and just comes up with a solid block of colour which doesn't always go away (usually when moderately-slowly resizing)

Static image (showing a diagonal resize):

> [image: Image with cyan background as well as usually site theme]

Gif of what happens (showing horizontal and vertical resizing):

> [image: Gif showing what happens when window is resized]

NB: This happens on meta pages (in a very light grey/white) and question pages too, though I haven't been able to get the home page to permanently display the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say: HALLE-FRICKIN-LUJAH for finally having a responsive theme!

<s>That being said, I'm not sure how I feel about having that left-side menu.</s> Oh hey, you can hide it!  Although now I'm extra confused about which "menu" to click for which options - I'm STILL clicking "Stack Exchange" to get the network dropdown and keep having to "re-find" the icon-only menu item. Now I've got a hamburger, an SE icon + text (which is ALSO icon-only, albeit taller and more colorful at mobile width), AND an SE icon itself (plus the review queue) which all trigger my monkey-brain tendency to want to click on it for the top-level site traversal options.

Comment: I hear 'ya. For now, this is by design. I'm hopeful we can change the design at some point, however.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to make the Review Queue dynamic like the notifications are?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just for me or is it normal that the menu moves from meta to normal puzzling:
[image: left menu]

[image: right menu]

I use chrome and the latest version (at least I should)

Comment: The profile pages are not yet fully responsive.

Answer (score 0):

[I know the question was already brought up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289114/show-solved-real-time-notification-for-chosen-non-favorite-questions),
but I'd really like a subscribe button which sends me a notification if the question was answered
(or a hint was added).
I'd like to have this here especially when I couldn't solve a riddle and like to see the solution or want to riddle again if a hint was added.
In fact I upvote the riddle sometimes, when I see how nice the solution of a riddle is.

Is a subscribe button still addable?